# Ícono de heroicons/vue dinámico

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt

Estoy tratando de realizar un sidebar dinámico, donde obtengo un array con las opciones del menú y dentro de estas opciones así:

```
const mainNavigation = [
        { title: 'Dashboard' },
        { title: 'Pages', icon:'DocumentIcon' },
        { title: 'Media', spacing: true, icon:'MediaIcon'  },
        {
            title: 'Projects', submenu: true,
            submenuItems: [
                { title: "Submenu 1" },
                { title: "Submenu 2" },
                { title: "Submenu 3" },
            ]
        },
        { title: 'Analitycs', icon:'AnalitycsIcon'  }
    ];
```

Estoy trabajando con nuxt 3 para crear dinámicamente mi ícono. He realizado un componente donde trabajar el ícono, el detalle está en que no me lo renderiza: no me muestra el ícono.

Aquí está mi componente:

```
<template>
    <div>
    <component :is="iconComponent" class="h-4 w-4 text-gray-300" />
  </div>
</template>
  
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps<{
  name: string;
}>();

const icons: { [key: string]: () => Promise<any> } = {
  home: () => import('@heroicons/vue/24/outline/HomeIcon.js'),
  user: () => import('@heroicons/vue/24/outline/UserIcon.vue'),
  // Agrega aquí más iconos según sea necesario
};

const iconComponent = computed(() => {
  return icons[props.name];
});
</script>
```

y aquí se encuentra donde mando a llamar al componente:

```
<DHeroIcon name="home" />
```

> Estoy empezando con Vue y desconozco si lo estoy haciendo bien.